# Nhibernate Where Exists queryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have the following objects

```
public class Document
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ISet<Tag> Tags { get; set;}
    ...
}

public class Tag 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;} 
}
```

This is a many to many relationship but I do not have an intermediate DocumentTag object. 
I am trying to use QueryOver syntax to return all documents that have all of a set of tags. Here is what i have so far.

```
Guid[] tagsThatMustMatch = ...;
var result = Session.QueryOver<Document>()
               .WithSubquery
               .WhereExists(QueryOver.Of<Tag>().Where(t => tagsThatMustMatch.Contains(t.Id))
               .List()
```

I am having trouble expressing the requirement. I understand that I have to dynamically construct a query which will have a WhereExists for each tag that must match. These WhereExists need to be anded. The other problem that I am having is that the WhereExists method needs to take in a DetachedQuery. But I have no way to constraining it to only look at the tags that this document has not all the tags.

Are there any examples out there where I can see how I can do something like this?

Answer (score 7):

Using **IN** - no need ot adjust Entity(ies) definition

Let's firstly declare your subquery this way:

```
Guid[] tagsThatMustMatch = ...;

var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Tag>()
 .WhereRestrictionOn(t => t.Id).IsIn(tagsThatMustMatch)
  .Select(t => t.Id); // tag ID projection
```

Having detached criteria, we can use them in a QueryOver syntax like this:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Document>()
  .JoinQueryOver<Tag>(d => d.Tags)
  .Where(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", subQuery.DetachedCriteria)) // Tag.Id
  // .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity) // distinct
  ;
```

EXTEND:

Using **EXISTS** - will require adjustment in our Entity Domain Model

As [Diego Jancic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72350/diego-jancic) pointed out in his comment, EXISTS could be more effective... but only if there is reference from `Tag` to `Document`

It could be either the reference

```
public class Tag 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;} 
    public Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

or at least the Guid representing the Doucment id

```
public class Tag 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;} 
    public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }
}
```

Let's assume the first, then we can use subquery like this

```
Guid[] tagsThatMustMatch = ...;

// Essential alias of the parent Document
Document document = null;

var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Tag>()
 .Where(t => t.Document.Id == document.Id) // or t.DocumentId = document.Id
 .WhereRestrictionOn(t => t.Id).IsIn(tagsThatMustMatch)
 .Select(t => t.Id); // tag ID projection
```

This is the only way, how the subquery would properly return true only on tags which relate to document. The exist query would than look like this

```
var query = session
    .QueryOver<Document>(() => document) // alias used in subquery
    .WithSubquery                        // needed to filter by parent id
        .WhereExists(subQuery)
    ...
```

Comment: -1 because there are 3 problems: 1) He asks for `EXISTS`, not `IN` or `JOIN`,  2) doing `X IN (select Id from T where Id IN (...))` is 'almost' the same than doing `X IN (...)` and 3) using a `JOIN` to do that is slow, `EXIST` should be used.

Comment: @DiegoJancic, I extended my answer with your suggested approach. It is not so trivial, because we have to extend the Domain model to make it happen, but now it will do *(as you mentioned)* better sql statement.Thanks a lot for a comment why downvoted. I admire that you appended the comment! Thanks for help to improve it

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. Changed to +1.